# Checking business logic in controller to provide better error messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a service method that returns a `UserDto` object. However there are several situations where the request to the controller would return a HTTP status other than 200 but the service can only return `null` or the `UserDto`.

Is it bad practice to move some of the business logic to the controller and call the repository directly in order to return more detailed error messages, since the service cannot pass back an error message to the contoller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a bit better by having the service throw business exception, and the controller react on that. For example, a CustomerService could throw a `CustomerNotFoundException', and the controller could turn that into an appropriate HTTP status code, like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ CustomerNotFoundException.class })
public ResponseEntity handleException(CustomerNotFoundException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), ex.getMessage(), request.getDescription(false));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

I recommend against moving the business logic to the controller, since the controller is more of an infrastructure component than domain logic. Also, consider adding another protocol, for example, a binary protocol, which wouldn't use the controller layer. You might miss your validations or business rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `@ControllerAdvice` from Spring to handle such cases, take a look at the below code.I hope this should help you return detailed error messages to the the controller.

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchUserException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoSuchPinCodeException(
        NoSuchUserException ex) {
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        apiError.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return buildResponseEntity(apiError);
    }

    private ResponseEntity<Object> buildResponseEntity(ApiError apiError) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(apiError, apiError.getStatus());
    }
}

public class NoSuchUserException extends Exception{         

    public NoSuchUserException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}

public class ApiError {

    private HttpStatus status;
    private String errorMessage;

    private ApiError() {
    }

    public ApiError(HttpStatus status) {
        this();
        this.status = status;
    }
    public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String errorMessage, Throwable ex) {
        this();
        this.status = status;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(HttpStatus status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

}
```